# How to detect when an app is launched on macOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsnotificationcenter

I have a background process running on the user’s macOS machine. Its job is to detect whenever any app is launched on the machine. Currently, I am detecting the `NSNotificationCenter`’s `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` event. This works perfectly for detecting when an app is freshly launched (i.e. the app had no instance already running at that time).

But, on macOS, if we click the red cross button at the top-left corner, it generally closes the app window and the app continues to run in the background. This is also evident by the app icon visible on the dock with the dot indicator below it. If I click the app icon on the dock and then launch it, the `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` event won’t be triggered.

To track such events, I tried using the `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` event. Using this event, I was able to detect all the app launch scenarios. The problem is that this event gets triggered whenever the app comes into focus such as switching windows using command+tab, clicking on its dock icon, changing between two apps, …

Is there a way to filter out these triggers or identify which action led to the trigger? Or is there some other event/ method I can listen to which gives the required filtered triggers? I only want to detect scenarios where a new window of the app is created.

Comment: The red button closes the window and some apps automatically quit when the last window is closed. If an app is running then it is not launched but activated. A new window can be created in many ways. What exactly do you want to detect?

Comment: @Willeke The apps that automatically quit when the last window is closed are not a problem. Consider the Notes app. I want to detect when a fresh instance of the app was launched and when the app is launched from the closed but not quit state (i.e. all app windows closed but the app did not quit. App launched again and creates a new window). What I don't want are the events when the user has the Notes app window open but went on Safari and then came back to the Notes app to continue working. Basically, I want to detect events of app window creation when there was no existing window.

Comment: An app is not launched if it is running. Some apps automatically create a new window or document when they are brought to the front. There is no "created new window because it was activated" event. Is it one specific app you want to monitor or any/all apps?

Comment: @Willeke Is there a way to detect if there were any visible windows at the time of trigger? I want to monitor any/ all apps. I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428638-applicationshouldhandlereopen?language=objc). But this is for a completely different purpose and also internal to the app and can't be used to monitor other apps.
Also, what if instead of all the apps, I have a list of some 10-15 specific apps that I want to monitor? Can it be done in this case?

Comment: I think it can be done but it won't be easy. If an app has no windows when it's deactivated and has a window after it's activated…

Answer (score 1):

What you seems to want is two different things, as was mentioned in comments, which should be processed separately to be reached.

1. To detect app launch, when the new process is started. You could use the NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification if it is enough (usually for visual user apps), or kqueue if it is not, or even EndpointSecurity framework to rule them all.
2. To track the window(s) in the already launched app. Visually, if the white dot under app dock icon is there, the app is still launched.
   There is an Accessibility framework for this task, you could track the event of window creation, window destruction, get count of windows from target process id, visibility state and etc.
   It is a bit abandoned and has no updates since maybe release, but it will work for you in most cases.

Comment: Agreed. Detecting the two things separately seems to be the best approach. For the first, `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` is enough. For the second, I tried out the Accessibility framework and using the `kAXWindowCreatedNotification`, I was able to detect the window creation events. Thanks! One issue though, Accessibility API unlike `NSNotificationCenter` require explicit user permission and action before they can be used. Is there a way to circumvent this? Or any other API that I can use? I just need the functionality similar to that of `kAXWindowCreatedNotification`.

Comment: There is intentionally no such API that could be used without user-granted permission. You still could enumerate all the windows, select only related to target PID, and check the adding/removing a window by your own with CG API: CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo. But there are other challenges here: 1) You will need to find some other, fitting your purposesm event to take a windows list or do it every small time period. 2) Not all information will be available until Screen Recording permission is granted

Comment: Is there a way to get the time when the window was created once I filter out the window related to the target PID from the list returned by `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`? Instead of polling, I can then use `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` and check if the active window was just created or it is just an already existing window becoming active.

Comment: No, I don't believe that the "creation time" way is possible. The only time you could get is the time of your actions to request windows list/status, there is no creationTime for window at all recorded in the system. 
However, you can distinguish the new window from old windows by saving the windows list for the target process, and comparing the new list, once requested, with saved one.